# How can i give a comment/Remarks for Dashboard report in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

After/Before generate report, how can i add/update dashboard report heading & comments in jmeter3,0.

Kindly give me a solution.

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As of JMeter 3.0 and 3.1, you would have to edit html and add comments.

You could request and enhancement:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html